# how to freeze a specific row in flextable using GWT

Tags: gwt

I have made a table showing data in various rows using GWT flextable but i have to freeze top rows at a relative position to the parent container. how to do that . please help me out in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You must create 2 flextables to achieve this.

The first is just the normal flextable you have currently.
The second contains only the headers, and has a fixed position on screen (the releative position).

The first flextable is always visible. The 2nd one is invisible at init.

Then when scrolling check if the relative position is reached. When it is reached make the 2nd flexTable visible. Now the 2nd flextable will appear on top of the first, and will give the illusion of it being a fixed header.